# How to obtain stock information from a website

Tags: web-access, html, api, http-functions, web

**I want to obtain some information of stock markets** from TradingView website.

For instance, let us access to S&P index chart through the URL,
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=SP%3ASPX

Now, one can find Stock Screener tab in the lower left in the website:
[image]

Clicking the tab and then the total amount of the screening result appears (The result is for Most Capitalized stocks in this example):
[image]

Now, you can see the total amount is 5483. My question is:
**Is it possible to get this number from Mathematica?**

Although I think my question is related to so called ``scraping’’, I am not familiar with web things (HTML, http, developer tools, api keys, etc.) at all, so I have no clue for this issue.

I tried `Import` which did not work:

```
Import["https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=SP%3ASPX","Data"]
```

Any comment is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: To get information on a particular stock e.g., do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Ons.png). The way you enter the spikey is = =.

Comment: Thank you. I do not want to get a particular stock information, but to get total information in a single market as breadth indicators. Mathematica does not seem to provide breadth indicators.

Comment: May I suggest you inquire about [Wolfram Finance Platform](https://www.wolfram.com/finance-platform/?source=nav).

Answer (score 1):

1. I do not think it is possible as it looks like TradingView has blocked scraping so `Import` does not work.

You can try the inbuilt function `FinancialData` to get lots of market data to see if that helps. The documentation is quite good here, but an example would be

```
properties = FinancialData["Apple", "Properties"];
data = FinancialData["Apple", #] & /@ properties;
Dataset[AssociationThread[properties, data]]
```

2. The general approach I use to scraping is to import the page and store the raw data. I then use F12 to inspect the webpage to figure out where in the raw data the element I want is. Sometimes using Ctrl+F to find where it is.

For example

```
rawData=Import["example.com"]
(*look on the website for the position of the data*)
dataIwant=rawData[[1]][[2]]
```

Some useful resources.

https://blog.wolfram.com/2018/03/02/web-scraping-with-the-wolfram-language-part-1-importing-and-interpreting/

https://www.scrapethissite.com/

3. You might have more luck scraping TradingView using Python modules *selenium* or *beautifulsoup*. A Google search will return more information about this.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. I know how to get information of individual stocks. What I want to get is TOTAL amount of all stock information in a single stock market (U.S. market in this case) to see the market conditions in a quantitative manner (e.g., Newhigh-newlow-index). Meanwhile, the website, scrapethissite, would be very helpful for me!

Comment: rawData = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies", "Data"]
rawComponents = rawData[[1]][[1]][[2]];(* from manually inspecting rawData*)
symbols = StringTrim /@ rawComponents[[2 ;;, 1]]; (* clean data*)
FinancialData[symbols[[1]]] (* you can do something less trivial here such as marketCaps=FinancialData[symbols, "MarketCap"]*)